# Communication of devices via AWS greengrass core

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am pretty new to AWS IoT. Can you please guide me or refer me some helpful material to implement whole greengrass. I want to use raspberry pi as my greengrass core in gg group and I want to establish communication between different devices which in my case are esp8266 and esp32 through raspberry pi.

I followed the official documentation given on aws site and implemented all examples given. In  4th module of aws greengrass core documentation they have shown an example in which two devices; publisher and subscriber, communicate with each other. As they mentioned I set up my computer as end device and run that basicDiscovery.py file in one terminal as publisher and subscriber in other terminal and it worked.

Now, instead of terminal in my computer I want to use one esp8266 as publisher and another esp8266 as subscriber and exchange data between them via raspberry pi (greengrass core).  I have no idea if I have to install device SDK on esp or what? I am finding no way out from here.

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Do you know what software the esp8266 is capable or running?

Answer (score 2):

You asked what software you need to run on your ESP8266 device in order to interact with AWS Greengrass. You have two software options to run on the ESP8266 that I'm aware of:

- FreeRTOS (FreeRTOS) is a very stable OS, and allows you to code in C.
- MongooseOS is a new OS and allows you to code in Javascript.
- Arduino (This [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Using-AWS-IoT-Serivce/) article walks you through registering a device with AWS IOT, which should allow you to connect it to Greengrass, but I recommend the above two options.)

**Amazon FreeRTOS**

1. To install the FreeRTOS software on your device, here are two tutorials:
   [install the FreeRTOS software](https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos) on your device.
   Here is another tutorial: [AWS IOT with FreeRTOS example](https://github.com/SuperHouse/esp-open-rtos/tree/master/examples/aws_iot).
2. Once you have the FreeRTOS software installed, you can continue in [Module 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/device-group.html) that you mentioned by adding the AWS IOT device (your ESP 8266) into your AWS Greengrass group.

**MongooseOS**

1. First, install the [mos](https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/aws) utility on your computer.
2. Next, use the `mos` utility to flash your device with [MongooseOS software](https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/aws).
3. Then, upload code to your device ([example](https://forum.mongoose-os.com/discussion/comment/3591/#Comment_3591)) to connect to AWS Greengrass Core (or, continue on with Module 4) as you noted.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First you should read about Greengrass which you can find useful information and how to install it on RaspberryPi [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html).
Then you should choose which kinds of OS you want to use for your ESPs. You can use:

- Amazon FreeRTOS
- MongooseOS
- Zerynth
- Or bare-metal programming with C/C++ using different IDEs like Arduino

I would recommend to use **Amazon FreeRTOS** because it is well-known and the documentations are very good. You can find more information to get started with it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/freertos-getting-started.html).

If you want to use **MongooseOS**, I should mention that the documentation is not good and you may lose your time for connecting your ESP to Greengrass group, although you can find more information about it in their blog [here](https://forum.mongoose-os.com/discussion/1199/aws-greengrass).

You can also use **Zerynth** which is based on python. It has also well documentation. Although, it doesn't support variety of micro controller manufacturers. You can find more information about it [here](https://docs.zerynth.com/latest/official/lib.aws.iot/docs/index.html).

If you want to use **Arduno** you can find more information [here](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/aws-greengrass-arduino-create/tree/master/extras).

Basically, Any AWS IoT device can connect to an AWS Greengrass core but you should consider the following hints:

- All of your devices (RaspberryPi and ESPs) should be in the same network and you should set the IP of the broker in your ESPs to the IP of your RaspberryPi in your local network.
- Also you should set the devices to be in same group in AWS IoT console and deploy the configuration to the Greengrass.
- The policies for IoT devices should allow them to publish/subscribe.
- For connecting to the AWS broker all of devices should have valid certifications and for connecting ESPs(or any other devices) to the Greengrass network, CA root certificate should be replaced by Greengrass group certificate.